# Should I use NTILE to get a distribution of data by datalength?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014.

I have a table with millions of rows which has a `varchar(max)` column called `[Description]`. The `MAX(DATALENGTH(Description))` is 30000.

I want to show a results set showing the distribution of the data by datalength in groups of 1000.

So the first row would show a count of rows that have a datalength between 0 and 1000, the second row would show a count of rows 1001-2000, etc. With a total of 30 rows (because they are groups of 1000).

Is NTILE the right tool for this? How would you write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ntile. Use this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) cnt, 
  DATALENGTH(Description)/1000 grp,
  CAST(DATALENGTH(Description)/1000 * 1000 as varchar(10)) +'-'+ 
    CAST((DATALENGTH(Description)/1000 + 1) * 1000 as varchar(10)) Interval
FROM @t
GROUP BY DATALENGTH(Description)/1000
```